# How to use shell keyword "select" to get parameters by pipeline?

Tags: bash, shell

My script v.sh

```
select f in "$@" ; do
    echo $f
done
```

`v.sh 1 2 3` I can select options after the command executed.

`echo 1 2 3 | v.sh` Showing nothing.

`echo 1 2 3 | xargs v.sh` Showing the options, but I can't select them.

How to select the options? Thx in advance.

Comment: To read stuff from standard input, use `read` keyword.

Comment: Thx all! The best answer has appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
  # no arguments, read from stdin
  mapfile -t input </dev/stdin
  exec </dev/tty
else
  # use arguments
  input=("$@")
fi

select f in "${input[@]}" ; do
  echo "$f"
done
```

Example with stdin:

```
cut -d : -f 1 /etc/passwd | ./script.sh
```

with arguments:

```
./script.sh 1 2 "3 3" 4 5
```

Comment: Nice! You finished it. Thx!